# grass r.watershed to larger rivers parallel lines to same stretch

Tags: grass-gis, watershed, parallel-lines

I'm trying create stream channels with **`r.watershed`** grass64. However, it shows two or three parallel lines for the same stretch of river. The river is large in some parts, but is just one river. Does anyone know if some tools to fix this exist? I tried to use **`v.clean`** with some parameters, but was unsuccessful.

Another option could be using a polygon layer for the river for these large parts and after this convert to line. This polygon already exists and is available. Would be a sort of 'reconditioning', how it is in ArcGIS, but using polygon instead lines.

Comment: I think you need to start by checking the elevation raster that you used for input to r.watershed

Comment: Yes, I did it. I used r.fillnulls.

Comment: Why fillnulls? What is the source of the DEM?